# Laravel - Send custom parameter to scheduled tasks (commands)

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I have 4 different commands in "app/Console/Commands/", and I set them all up in app/Kernel.php, like this:

```
$schedule->command('command:start-imports-group-a')->everyFiveMinutes()->runInBackground()->withoutOverlapping();
$schedule->command('command:start-imports-group-b')->everyFiveMinutes()->runInBackground()->withoutOverlapping();    
$schedule->command('command:start-imports-group-c')->everyFiveMinutes()->runInBackground()->withoutOverlapping();    
$schedule->command('command:start-imports-group-d')->everyFiveMinutes()->runInBackground()->withoutOverlapping();
```

In my command php files (e.g. StartImportsGroupA.php, StartImportsGroupB.php, etc.) they are all calling the same function, but I'm simply setting a variable in each to change the "group" value. For example:

StartImportsGroupA.php

```
public function handle()
{
     $group = 'a';
     $this->startImports($group);
}
```

StartImportsGroupB.php

```
public function handle()
{
     $group = 'b';
     $this->startImports($group);
}
```

...and so on.

**Is there an better way to do this?** E.g. pass the "group" parameter to the command? That way I won't need 4 different command files to simply change that one $group variable's value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks **SpinyMan**, although I had to do some more research for the remainder of the answer. The full answer is this:

1. Set the [arguments](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#arguments) (you can pass options also) in the $signature
2. Specify an array as the second value of $schedule->command(), each value is in order, containing the value to be passed. Since {group} is mentioned first in the $signature, that value should be the first value in the array passed to $schedule->command()
3. Retrieve the argument (or option) value in handle() as needed

**Working Example:**

In app/Console/Commands/StartImports.php file:

```
protected $signature = 'command:start-imports {group}';

public function handle()
{
        $group = $this->argument('group');
}
```

In app/Console/Kernel.php file:

```
$schedule->command('command:start-imports', ['a'])->everyFiveMinutes()->runInBackground()->withoutOverlapping();
$schedule->command('command:start-imports', ['b'])->everyFiveMinutes()->runInBackground()->withoutOverlapping();
$schedule->command('command:start-imports', ['c'])->everyFiveMinutes()->runInBackground()->withoutOverlapping();
$schedule->command('command:start-imports', ['d'])->everyFiveMinutes()->runInBackground()->withoutOverlapping();
```

I hope this helps anyone else who needs this!

Answer (score 3):

You can use second parameter as array of options for your command:

```php
$schedule->command(StartImportsGroupCommand::class, ['--group=a'])
    ->everyFiveMinutes()
    ->runInBackground()
    ->withoutOverlapping();
```

Do not forget to describe this option `--group` in command code.